# Python Orange (Version 3.3.6) on Window 10 can't create demo widget

Tags: python, widget, orange

As per [the documentation](http://orange-development.readthedocs.io/tutorial-cont.html), I created the following files:

**setup.py** (in folder `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\Orange\widgets\orange-demo`)

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="Demo",
      packages=["orangedemo"],
      package_data={"orangedemo": ["icons/*.svg"]},
      classifiers=["Example :: Invalid"],
      # Declare orangedemo package to contain widgets for the "Demo" category
      entry_points={"orange.widgets": "Demo = orangedemo"},
      )
```

and **OWDataSamplerA.py** (in folder `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\Orange\widgets\orange-demo\orangedemo`)

```
import sys
import numpy

import Orange.data
from Orange.widgets import widget, gui

class OWDataSamplerA (widget.OWWidget):
    name = "Data Sampler"
    description = "Randomly selects a subset of instances from the data set"
    icon = "icons/DataSamplerA.svg"
    priority = 10

    inputs = [("Data", Orange.data.Table, "set_data")]
    outputs = [("Sampled Data", Orange.data.Table)]

    want_main_area = False

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # GUI
        box = gui.widgetBox(self.controlArea, "Info")
        self.infoa = gui.widgetLabel(box, 'No data on input yet, waiting to get something.')
        self.infob = gui.widgetLabel(box, '')

    def set_data(self, dataset):
        if dataset is not None:
            self.infoa.setText('%d instances in input data set' % len(dataset))
            indices = numpy.random.permutation(len(dataset))
            indices = indices[:int(numpy.ceil(len(dataset) * 0.1))]
            sample = dataset[indices]
            self.infob.setText('%d sampled instances' % len(sample))
            self.send("Sampled Data", sample)
        else:
            self.infoa.setText('No data on input yet, waiting to get something.')
            self.infob.setText('')
            self.send("Sampled Data", None)
```

I created a .svg icon and left the `__init__.py` file blank. After running `pip install -e .`, a `Demo.egg-info` directory is created and it includes several files, but no demo widget is created. After restarting Python Orange no visible changes occur at all.

Any advice would be most welcome.

Comment: Please add the `python` tag and check if the used `orange` tag semantics is  correct for your case (I suspect it's a wrong tag in this context). Also please put your `pip` usage into a code wrapper. Best regards.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this documentation?

Comment: 1) you should not create the project structure inside `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\Orange`.

2) Please try running `C:\Python34\python.exe -m Orange.canvas -l3` and look for any errors/messages regarding the Demo project.

Comment: I had the same problem. The documentation source is this: http://orange3.readthedocs.io/projects/orange-development/tutorial-cont.html#a-demo-package
But i found an example addon package that works: https://github.com/biolab/orange3-example-addon Just download zip, extract and install using pip install -e

Answer (score 0):

A separate version of **Python 3.6** is bundled with Orange.

To install a new widget, you need to have the proper Python instance in the path.

On Windows, you can find a special shortcut "Orange Command Prompt". You will need to run it as Administrator to install new packages in newer version.

[image: Orange Command Prompt]

Once in the appropriate directory, you can run your `pip install..` command.

[image: pip install orange widget]